# Replace ab in string |var11=ab|var12=100|var21=cd|var22=200| using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

i want to replace `ab` followed by `var11` in given string

Input:`|var11=ab|var12=100|var21=cd|var22=200|`

My code is as follows:

```
string input = "|var11=ab|var12=100|var21=cd|var22=200|";
string pattern = @"^.var11=([a-z]+).";
string value = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "ep");
```

and the output I got is:

> epvar12=100|var21=cd|var22=200|

but the expected output was:

> |var11=**ep**|var12=100|var21=cd|var22=200|

Comment: `Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "|var11=ep|")`

Comment: when building a regex and not getting what you expect a debugger is nice like this one https://www.debuggex.com/

What you see there is that your regex match on the substring part |var11=ab| and then you replace that match with "ep" a solution would be to simply replace that with  "|var11=ep|" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
string input = "|var11=ab|var12=100|var21=cd|var22=200|";
string pattern = @"(?<=\bvar11=)[^|]+";
string value = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "ep");
```

Or, a capturing group approach:

```
string pattern = @"\b(var11=)[^|]+";
string value = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "${1}ep");
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5Cbvar11%3D%29%5B%5E%7C%5D%2B&i=%7Cvar11%3Dab%7Cvar12%3D100%7Cvar21%3Dcd%7Cvar22%3D200%7C&r=ep)

**Details**

- `(?<=\bvar11=)` - a location immediately preceded with a whole word `var11=`
- `[^|]+` - 1+ non-pipe chars.

If you want to update the `var11` value only when it is preceded with `|` or at the start of string use

```
string pattern = @"(?<=(?:^|\|)var11=)[^|]+";
```

where `(?:^|\|)` matches start of string (`^`) or (`|`) a pipe char (`\|`).

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, what if i also have to handle spaces eg|var11= ab |

Comment: @abhi Use `string pattern = @"(?<=\bvar11=\s*)[^\s|]+";` or `string pattern = @"(?<=\bvar11=\s*)[^\s|]+";` where `\s` matches any whitespace chars.

Comment: also +1 for the explanation it helped me understanding regex better,